# Biblatex: Footnotes with parentheses around year

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm working with Latex on my master thesis and I use biblatex for my citations and bibliography. 
The citation format I look for is with in footnotes:
"Vgl. Author1 / Author2 (Year), S. 100"

Actually I've got everything working as I wished, but after updating to MikTex 2.9 I cannot get the parentheses to work at all.

Example code:

```
    % Festlegung des Allgemeinen Dokumentenformats
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headsepline]{scrartcl}

% Umlaute unter UTF8 nutzen
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Deutsche Sonderzeichen und Silbentrennung nutzen
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}% Recommended

% Eurozeichen einbinden
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}

% Zeichenencoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


% Für Literaturverzeichnis
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}

@BOOK{Herrmann_Huber:Produktmanagement,
  AUTHOR       = {Herrmann, A. and Huber, F.},

  TITLE        = {Produktmanagement: Grundlagen - Methoden - Beispiele},

  PUBLISHER    = {Springer Gabler},
  YEAR         = {2013},
  ADDRESS      = {Wiesbaden},
  Edition      = {3},
}

@BOOK{Eigner:ProductLifecycleManagement,
  AUTHOR       = {Eigner, M. and Stelzer, R.},

  TITLE        = {Product Lifecycle Management: Ein Leitfaden für Product Development und Life Cycle Management},

  PUBLISHER    = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
  YEAR         = {2009},
  ADDRESS      = {Heidelberg},
  Edition      = {2},
}


@BOOK{Herrmann:GanzheitlichesLifeCycleManagement,
  AUTHOR       = {Herrmann, C.},

  TITLE        = {Ganzheitliches Life Cycle Management: Nachhaltigkeit und Lebenszyklusorientierung in Unternehmen},

  PUBLISHER    = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
  YEAR         = {2010},
  ADDRESS      = {Heidelberg},

}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=authoryear,
            dashed=false,
            maxcitenames=2,
            maxbibnames=99
            ]{biblatex}

%--------------------------------------------------
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

%paranthesis around year
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperrefparens}{\bibhyperref{\mkbibparens{#1}}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
\iffieldundef{labelyear}
   {}%
      {\printtext[bibhyperrefparens]{%
          \printfield[]{labelyear}%
          \printfield[]{extrayear}%
          }%
      }%
}




\begin{document}
Test. \smartcite[Vgl.][\pno~1]{Eigner:ProductLifecycleManagement} \smartcite[Vgl.][\pno~1]{Herrmann:GanzheitlichesLifeCycleManagement} \newline
Test \autocite[Vgl.][\pno~3]{Albers_Herrmann:Handbuch_Produktmanagement} 
\footcite[Vgl.][\pno~124\psq]{Herrmann_Huber:Produktmanagement} \newline
Test. 
\newpage


% Literaturliste soll im Inhaltsverzeichnis auftauchen
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis}
% Literaturverzeichnis anzeigen
\renewcommand\refname{Literaturverzeichnis}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

What I used earlier and what was giving me the result I wished for was this:

```
    % Festlegung des Allgemeinen Dokumentenformats
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headsepline]{scrartcl}

% Umlaute unter UTF8 nutzen
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Variablen
\input{latex_einstellungen/variablen}

% neue Befehle
%\newcommand{\sectionnumbering}[1]{% 
 % \setcounter{section}{0}% 
  % \renewcommand{\thesection}{\csname #1\endcsname{section}}}     

% weitere Pakete
% Grafiken aus PNG Dateien einbinden
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}


% Deutsche Sonderzeichen und Silbentrennung nutzen
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% Eurozeichen einbinden
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}

% Zeichenencoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Schriftart Helvet verwenden
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{lmodern}

% floatende Bilder ermöglichen
%\usepackage{floatflt}

% mehrseitige Tabellen ermöglichen
\usepackage{longtable}

% Unterstützung für Schriftarten
%\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{ 
%\fontfamily{#1} \fontseries{#2} \fontshape{#3} \selectfont}

% Packet für Seitenrandabständex und Einstellung für Seitenränder
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=3.0cm, right=4.0cm, top=2.0cm, bottom=2.0cm}
%\geometry{includehead}
%\geometry{includefoot}  % hinzugefügt für Kopf- und Fußzeilenposition
\geometry{headheight=25pt}               % gemäß Warning von \fancyhdr =  24.35
\geometry{footskip = 24pt}
\geometry{heightrounded}                     % gegen Warnungen
%\geometry{\showframe}


% Paket für Boxen im Text
\usepackage{fancybox}

% bricht lange URLs "schön" um
\usepackage[hyphens,obeyspaces,spaces]{url}

% Paket für Textfarben
\usepackage{color}

% Mathematische Symbole importieren
\usepackage{amssymb}

% auf jeder Seite eine Überschrift (alt, zentriert)
%\pagestyle{headings}

% erzeugt Inhaltsverzeichnis mit Querverweisen zu den Abschnitten (PDF Version)
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,pdftitle={\titleDocument},hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=red, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=black}
%\hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=black, linkcolor= black, urlcolor=black}


% Kopf- und Fußzeile aus anderer NAK Latex Vorlage
\RequirePackage[bottom,multiple]{footmisc} %multiple: mehrere Fußnoten hintereinander mit Komma trennen
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} %eigener Seitenstil
\fancyhf{} %alle Kopf- und Fußzeilenfelder bereinigen
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[height=20pt]{abb/Logo_NAK}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} %Seitennummer
%\setlength{\footskip}{10mm}


% für Tabellen
\usepackage{array}

% fürs Abkürzungsverzeichnis
\usepackage{acronym}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Für Literaturverzeichnis

% Biblatex: Folgenden Befehl verwenden: biber %

\usepackage{csquotes}% Recommended

\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=authoryear-ibid,
            dashed=false,
            maxcitenames=2,
            maxbibnames=99
            ]{biblatex}

%--------------------- Vorerst nicht mehr benötigt          
%\makeatletter

%\newrobustcmd*{\parentexttrack}[1]{%
%  \begingroup
%  \blx@blxinit
%  \blx@setsfcodes
%  \blx@bibopenparen#1\blx@bibcloseparen
%  \endgroup}

%\AtEveryCite{%
%  \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
%  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
%  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}

%\makeatother
%--------------------------------------------------

% Autoren anders zu trennen [ "/" statt "und"]:
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace/\space}
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace/\space}}

%ersetzt "u.a." durch "et al."
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers = {et\addnbspace al\adddot}}


%Runde Klammern um Jahreszahl in den Fußnoten
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperrefparens}{\bibhyperref{\mkbibparens{#1}}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
\iffieldundef{labelyear}
   {}%
      {\printtext[bibhyperrefparens]{%
          \printfield[]{labelyear}%
          \printfield[]{extrayear}%
          }%
      }%
}

%-Alle Autoren werden in der Form "Nachname, Name" dargestellt
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

%Nachpflegen: Bei Dissertationen Titel auch kursiv, nicht in ""
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[PhdThesis]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1\isdot}}

% Initialen von Vornamen in Fußzeile hinter Nachnamen
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

% 
%--- |Einrueckung der Fussnoten |--------------------------
\deffootnote{1em}{1em}{%
\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark\ }
}
%----------------------------------------------------------


% *.Bib Datei laden
\addbibresource[]{./Hauptdatei.bib}


%------------------------------Abstand zwischen den einzelnen Einträgen im Literaturverzeichnis--------
\bibitemsep=\itemsep
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\itemsep}
%--------------------------

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% Schaltet den zusätzlichen Zwischenraum ab, den LaTeX normalerweise nach einem Satzzeichen einfügt.
%\frenchspacing

% Paket für Zeilenabstand
\usepackage{setspace}

% für Bildbezeichner
\usepackage{capt-of}

% für Stichwortverzeichnis
\usepackage{makeidx}

% für Listings
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, numbersep=5pt, keywordstyle=\color{black}\bfseries, stringstyle=\ttfamily,showstringspaces=false,basicstyle=\footnotesize,captionpos=b}
\lstset{language=java}

% Indexerstellung
\makeindex

% Abkürzungsverzeichnis
\usepackage[german]{nomencl}
\let\abbrev\nomenclature

% Abkürzungsverzeichnis LiveTex Version
% Titel des Abkürzungsverzeichnisses
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
% Abstand zwischen Abkürzung und Erläuterung
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.25\textwidth}
% Zwischenraum zwischen Abkürzung und Erläuterung mit Punkten
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1 \dotfill}
% Variation des Abstandes der einzelnen Abkürzungen zu einander
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}
% Index mit Abkürzungen erzeugen
\makenomenclature
%\makeglossary

%Abkürzungsverzeichnis
\newcommand{\abkuerzungsverzeichnis}{
    \newpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
    \section*{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
    \fancyhead[L]{Abkürzungsverzeichnis} %Kopfzeile links
    \printnomenclature[3cm]
    \begin{acronym}[XXXXXX] %Anzahl der X: max. Abkürzungslänge für einheitlichen Abstand im Verzeichnis
        \acro{B2B}{Business-To-Business}
        \acro{B2C}{Business-To-Consumer}
    \end{acronym}
    %\ac{ecu}   European currency unit (ECU)
    %\acs{ecu}  ECU
    %\acl{ecu}  European currency unit
    %\acp{ecu}  ECUs
    %\acfp{ecu} European currency units (ECUs)
}

% Abkürzungsverzeichnis TeTEX Version
% \usepackage[german]{nomencl}
% \makenomenclature
% %\makeglossary
% \renewcommand{\nomname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
% \AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.25\columnwidth}}
% \renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1 \dotfill}
% \setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}

% Optional: Einzelne Zeilen am Anfang einer Seite unterdrücken (Schusterjungen)
% \clubpenalty = 10000
% Optional: Einzelne Zeilen am Ende einer Seite unterdrücken (Hurenkinder)
% \widowpenalty = 10000
% \displaywidowpenalty = 10000

\begin{document}
% hier werden die Trennvorschläge inkludiert
\input{latex_einstellungen/trennung}

% Schriftart Helvetica verwenden
%\usepackage{helvet}
%\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

% Leere Seite am Anfang
%\thispagestyle{empty} % erzeugt Seite ohne Kopf- / Fusszeile
%\mbox{}
%\newpage

% Titelseite %
\input{latex_einstellungen/deckblatt}

% römische Numerierung
\pagenumbering{Roman} 
% \setcounter{page}{5} falls benötigt

% 1.5 facher Zeilenabstand
\onehalfspacing

%  Abstract
\input{abstract}
\fancyhead[L]{Abstract} %Kopfzeile links

% einfacher Zeilenabstand
\singlespacing

% Inhaltsverzeichnis anzeigen
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\fancyhead[L]{Inhaltsverzeichnis} %Kopfzeile links

% das Abbildungsverzeichnis
\newpage
% Abbildungsverzeichnis soll im Inhaltsverzeichnis auftauchen
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
% Verion 1: Abbildungsverzeichnis MIT führender Nummberierung endgueltig anzeigen
\listoffigures
\fancyhead[L]{Abbildungsverzeichnis} %Kopfzeile links

% Verion 2: Abbildungsverzeichnis OHNE führende Nummberierung endgueltig anzeigen
%\begingroup
%\renewcommand\numberline[1]{}
%\listoffigures
%\endgroup


% das Tabellenverzeichnis
\newpage
% Tabellenverzeichnis soll im Inhaltsverzeichnis auftauchen
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tabellenverzeichnis}

% Tabellenverzeichnis endgültig anzeigen
\listoftables
\fancyhead[L]{Tabellenverzeichnis} %Kopfzeile links

%% WORKAROUND für Listings
%\makeatletter% --> De-TeX-FAQ
%\renewcommand*{\lstlistoflistings}{%
%  \begingroup
%    \if@twocolumn
%      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
%    \else
%      \@restonecolfalse
%    \fi
%    \lol@heading
%    \setlength{\parskip}{\z@}%
%    \setlength{\parindent}{\z@}%
%    \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ \@plus 1fil}%
%    \@starttoc{lol}%
%    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
%  \endgroup
%}
%\makeatother% --> \makeatletter
% das Listingverzeichnis
%\newpage
% Listingverzeichnis soll im Inhaltsverzeichnis auftauchen
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Listingverzeichnis}
%\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Listingverzeichnis}
%\lstlistoflistings
%%%%

% das Abkürzungsverzeichnis
\abkuerzungsverzeichnis
%\input{latex_einstellungen/abkuezungen/abkuerzungen}
%\printnomenclature[3cm]

%\fancyhead[L]{Abkürzungsverzeichnis} %Kopfzeile links
    % Abkürzungsverzeichnis soll im Inhaltsverzeichnis auftauchen
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}



%%%%%%% EINLEITUNG %%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
%von hier an arabische Nummerierung verwenden 
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
%\sectionnumbering{arabic}

\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}} %Kopfzeile links

% 1,5 facher Zeilenabstand
\onehalfspacing

% einzelne Abschnitte
\input{1_einleitung}
\setlength{\footskip}{10mm}
\newpage

\input{2_kap1}
\setlength{\footskip}{10mm}
\newpage

\input{3_kap2}
\newpage
%....

\input{7_ausblick}
\newpage

\input{8_fazit}
\newpage

\input{beispiel}
\newpage

% einfacher Zeilenabstand
\singlespacing
% Literaturliste soll im Inhaltsverzeichnis auftauchen
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis}
% Literaturverzeichnis anzeigen
\renewcommand\refname{Literaturverzeichnis}
\printbibliography

%% Index soll Stichwortverzeichnis heissen
% \newpage
% % Stichwortverzeichnis soll im Inhaltsverzeichnis auftauchen
% \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Stichwortverzeichnis}
% \renewcommand{\indexname}{Stichwortverzeichnis}
% % Stichwortverzeichnis endgültig anzeigen
% \printindex

\onehalfspacing
% evtl. Anhang
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Anhang}
\fancyhead[L]{Anhang} %Kopfzeile links
\input{anhang/anhang}

% Sperrvermerk
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Sperrvermerk}
\fancyhead[L]{Sperrvermerk} %Kopfzeile links
\input{sperrvermerk}

% Eidesstattliche Erklärung
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Eidesstattliche Erklärung}
\input{erklaerung}

% leere Abschlussseite
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty} % erzeugt Seite ohne Kopf- / Fusszeile
\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

The error message I receive now after the update is this:
"! Illegal parameter number in definition of \blx@defformat@d.3 \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3"
And several more of this kind.

Due to that, I adjusted the code to show the first letter of the given name after the family name inside one footling, in case two authors have the same family name. I did some more tweaking regarding some other issues in my current version, but the only thing not working is the part with the parenthesis around the year number, which is not even working on the basic example above.

I tried several solutions I found on the internet now to get the parenthesis to work, but neither of them worked so far (Not used them at the same time of course).

```
%% Option  1:
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperrefparens}{\bibhyperref{\mkbibparens{#1}}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
\iffieldundef{labelyear}
   {}%
      {\printtext[bibhyperrefparens]{%
          \printfield[]{labelyear}%
          \printfield[]{extrayear}%
          }%
      }%
}

%% Option 2:
\DeclareFieldFormat{year}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\AtBeginBibliography{\DeclareFieldFormat{year}{#1}}

%% Option 3:
%in Fusszitaten Jahre in Klammern
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
\iffieldundef{labelyear}
{}
{\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
\mkbibparens{%
\printfield{labelyear}%
\printfield{extrayear}}}}}
%

%% Option 4:
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printfield{labelyear}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{extrayear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{extrayear}}}}}
```

Maybe someone has an idea what could resolve my issue?
I'm using MikTex 2.9 + Texmaker.
Thank you!

Edit:

Here my current file, so that you get the idea what the citations should look like:

```
% Festlegung des Allgemeinen Dokumentenformats
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headsepline]{scrartcl}

% Umlaute unter UTF8 nutzen
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% For graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}


% German special characters  
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% euro signs
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}

% Zeichenencoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% font type  Helvet 
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{lmodern}

% floatende Bilder ermöglichen
%\usepackage{floatflt}

% tables among several sites
\usepackage{longtable}

% Unterstützung für Schriftarten
%\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{ 
%\fontfamily{#1} \fontseries{#2} \fontshape{#3} \selectfont}

% used for page dimensions
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=3.0cm, right=4.0cm, top=2.0cm, bottom=2.0cm}
%\geometry{includehead}
%\geometry{includefoot}  % hinzugefügt für Kopf- und Fußzeilenposition
\geometry{headheight=25pt}               % gemäß Warning von \fancyhdr =  24.35
\geometry{footskip = 24pt}
\geometry{heightrounded}                     % gegen Warnungen
%\geometry{\showframe}


% Boxes inside texts
\usepackage{fancybox}

% new line for long URLs
\usepackage[hyphens,obeyspaces,spaces]{url}

% text colors
\usepackage{color}

% Mathematic symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}


% Head and foot line definitions
\RequirePackage[bottom,multiple]{footmisc} %multiple: mehrere Fußnoten hintereinander mit Komma trennen
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} %eigener Seitenstil
\fancyhf{} %alle Kopf- und Fußzeilenfelder bereinigen
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[height=20pt]{abb/Logo_NAK}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} %Seitennummer
%\setlength{\footskip}{10mm}

% for Tables
\usepackage{array}

% for acronyms
\usepackage{acronym}

%%%% For bibliogryphy

\usepackage{csquotes}% Recommended

\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=authoryear-ibid,
            dashed=false,
            maxcitenames=2,
            maxbibnames=99
            ]{biblatex}

%--------------------------------------------------

% several Authors devided by  "/" instead of "und":
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace/\space}
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace/\space}}

% adjust "u.a." through "et al."
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    andothers = {et\addnbspace al\adddot},
    editor = {\mkbibparens{Hrsg\adddot}},  %(Hrsg.)
}

%all authors will be shown with "family name, given name "
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first} 

% make title italic, no ""
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[PhdThesis]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1\isdot}} 

% Footnotes: parenthesis for year --- not working at the moment
%% Option  1:
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperrefparens}{\bibhyperref{\mkbibparens{#1}}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
\iffieldundef{labelyear}
   {}%
      {\printtext[bibhyperrefparens]{%
          \printfield[]{labelyear}%
          \printfield[]{extrayear}%
          }%
      }%
}


% For editors: After names of editors "(Hrsg.)" should be written in bibliography 
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{% %Hg. bzw Hgg. in Klammern hinter Herausgeber, statt davor
 \ifnameundef{editor}
 {}
 {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
 \setunit{\addspace}%
 \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
 \clearname{editor}%
 \newunit}%
 \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
 \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}
% 
%inbook: 
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
}%
  {%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  }%
  {}{}%


%% First letter of given name after family name in footlines (in case two authors have the same family name)
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefixi}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
%---------------------------------------------------

% 
% Space after footnote (horizontal distance)
\deffootnote{1em}{1em}{%
\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark\ }
}
%----------------------------------------------------------


% load *.Bib file 
\addbibresource[]{./Hauptdatei.bib}


% Distance between entries in bibliography
\bibitemsep=\itemsep
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\itemsep}
%--------------------------




\begin{document}

Test  \smartcite[Vgl.][\pno~1]{Eigner:ProductLifecycleManagement} \newline
Test  \smartcite[Vgl.][\pno~1]{Herrmann:GanzheitlichesLifeCycleManagement} \newline
Test \smartcite[Vgl.][\pno~3]{Albers_Herrmann:Handbuch_Produktmanagement} \newline
Test \smartcite[Vgl.][\pno~124\psq]{Herrmann_Huber:Produktmanagement} \newline
Test \smartcite[Vgl.][\pno~3]{Herrmann_Huber:Produktmanagement}\newline
Test \smartcite[Vgl.][\pno~12]{Herrmann_Huber:Produktmanagement} 
Test \smartcite{TROMMSDORFF} \newline

% Literaturliste soll im Inhaltsverzeichnis auftauchen
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis}
% Literaturverzeichnis anzeigen
\renewcommand\refname{Literaturverzeichnis}
\printbibliography


% leere Abschlussseite
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty} % erzeugt Seite ohne Kopf- / Fusszeile
\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

With bib file 'Hauptdatei.bib'

```
@BOOK{Albers_Herrmann:Handbuch_Produktmanagement,
  AUTHOR       = {Albers, S. and Herrmann, A.},

  TITLE        = {{H}andbuch {P}roduktmanagement: Strategieentwicklung - Produktplanung - Organisation - Kontrolle},

  PUBLISHER    = {Gabler Verlag},
  YEAR         = {2007},
  ADDRESS      = {Wiesbaden},
  Edition      = {3},
  Editor = {Albers, S. and Herrmann, A.},
}


@BOOK{Herrmann_Huber:Produktmanagement,
  AUTHOR       = {Herrmann, A. and Huber, F.},

  TITLE        = {Produktmanagement: Grundlagen - Methoden - Beispiele},

  PUBLISHER    = {Springer Gabler},
  YEAR         = {2013},
  ADDRESS      = {Wiesbaden},
  Edition      = {3},
}

@BOOK{Eigner:ProductLifecycleManagement,
  AUTHOR       = {Eigner, M. and Stelzer, R.},

  TITLE        = {Product Lifecycle Management: Ein Leitfaden für Product Development und Life Cycle Management},

  PUBLISHER    = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
  YEAR         = {2009},
  ADDRESS      = {Heidelberg},
  Edition      = {2},
}


@BOOK{Herrmann:GanzheitlichesLifeCycleManagement,
  AUTHOR       = {Herrmann, C.},

  TITLE        = {Ganzheitliches Life Cycle Management: Nachhaltigkeit und Lebenszyklusorientierung in Unternehmen},

  PUBLISHER    = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
  YEAR         = {2010},
  ADDRESS      = {Heidelberg},

}

@BOOK{Stark:ProductLifecycleManagement,
  AUTHOR       = {Stark, J.},

  TITLE        = {Product Lifecycle Management (Volume 1): 21st Century Paradigm for Product Realisation},

  PUBLISHER    = {Springer International Publishing},
  YEAR         = {2020},
  ADDRESS      = {Cham},
  Edition      = {4},
}

@PhdThesis{Gentner:AnalytischeMethodenB2B,
author = {Gentner, D.},
title = {Analytische Methoden im B2B Produktmanagement der verarbeitenden Industrie: Analyse des Kundenpotenzials anhand kunden- und produktbezogener Indikatoren},
school = {Universität Ulm},
location = {Deutschland},
year = {2019},
OPTtype = {Wirtschaftswissenschaften},
}

@PhdThesis{Osswald:StrategischesProduktmanagement,
author = {Oßwald, M.},
title = {Strategisches Produktmanagement im
Maschinen- und Anlagenbau: Methode und Umsetzungsempfehlungen},
school = {Universität Ulm},
location = {Deutschland},
year = {2016},
OPTtype = {Wirtschaftswissenschaften},
}




@inbook{TROMMSDORFF,
author = {TROMMSDORFF, V},
title = {Produktpositionierung},
booktitle = {{H}andbuch {P}roduktmanagement: Strategieentwicklung - Produktplanung - Organisation - Kontrolle},
year = {2007},
OPTbookauthor = {Albers, S. and Herrmann, A.},
editor = {Albers, S. and Herrmann, A.},
edition = {3},
publisher = {Gabler Verlag},
location = {Wiesbaden},
pages = {359-380},
}



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that it can be tricky to change a simple thing like adding parentheses around the year in `\footcite` was one of the motivations to write [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext).

With the drop-in replacement styles of `biblatex-ext` you can add parentheses around the year in `\footcite` with the single line

```
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{footcite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}
```

You may also be interested in the `biblatex-ext` option `innamebeforetitle`.

For the MWE I tried to modernise your other code as well.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headsepline]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}


\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=ext-authoryear,
            innamebeforetitle=true,
            autocite=footnote,
            dashed=false,
            maxcitenames=2,
            maxbibnames=99
            ]{biblatex}


\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addspace/\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias*{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers = {et\addnbspace al\adddot}}

\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{footcite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite[Vgl.][1]{sigfridsson}
ipsum\autocite[Vgl.][1]{worman}
dolor\footcite[Vgl.][124\psq]{geer}
sit\smartcite[Vgl.][1]{nussbaum}
amet.\autocite[Vgl.][1]{westfahl:frontier,westfahl:space}

\clearpage
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Vgl. Sigfridsson / Ryde (1998), S. 1.]

Comment: You made my day! Thanks for the quick response and also for the optimizations. Solution worked very well.